# smooth manifold, diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I've been reading the text Introduction to Manifold by Loring W. Tu and according to his definition,

A smooth or $ C^{\infty}$ is a topological manifold $M$ together with a maximal atlas and a topological manifold is a Hausdorff, second countable and locally Euclidean space.

Now, consider the graph of the function, $y = |x|  ~~, -1 < x < 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The graph of this function is a smooth manifold since being a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is second countable and Hausdorff, and it also has an atlas consisting of a single chart, 
$$ \phi(x,y) = x ~~\text{with}~~\phi^{-1}(x) = (x, |x|)  ,~~ -1 < x < 1  .$$

Later on in the book, he proved that the coordinate map, $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism which means that its inverse is $C^{\infty}$, but from the example above, $ \phi^{-1}(x)$ is not differentiable at $ x = 0$,  how can this be though?? I know I did something wrong to get to this conclusion but I don't know what I did wrong.  Thank you very much.

Comment: No, with the atlas it inherits sitting in $\Bbb R^2$ it is *not* a smooth manifold. $\phi^{-1}$ is obviously *not* even differentiable, let alone smooth. The differentiable structure Tu wants to give it is a different one. Can you figure that out?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the reply.  I know that the graph is a topological manifold, is that right? To show that a topological manifold is a smooth manifold according to Tu, we need to show that it has an atlas.  So by what you said, I would guess that this topological manifold does not have any atlas since it would fail the compatibility of charts, is that what you meant?

Comment: You have not yet given the *right* atlas. :) In fairness, this is a confusing point for all of us when we begin with this material.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the reply.  Can you clarify what you meant more?  I'm confused now.

Comment: We've already agreed that as this curve sits in $\Bbb R^2$ it is not a smooth submanifold but only a topological submanifold. But you said it was homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. How can you use this latter fact?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry for the late reply, I gotta attend family event yesterday.  I read some notes and question posted here and I think I understand a little bit more by what you meant.  Like you said, if we consider the graph sitting in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then any coordinate chart needs to be diffeomorphism but $\phi$ is obviously not so then in that sense, it is not a smooth manifold.  But since the graph is homeomorphic to R, what if we consider the graph as a topological manifold with a differentiable structure consist of a single chart by $\phi$ defined above? is it a smooth manifold then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50745/discussion-between-khoa-ta-and-ted-shifrin).